# How to run two threads parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I start two threads with a button click and each thread invokes a separate routine and each routine will print thread name and value of `i`.

Program runs perfectly, but I saw `Thread1()` function running first and then `Thread2()` routine starts, but I try to run `Thread1()` and `Thread2()` both in parallel. Where am I making a mistake?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
    Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));

    tid1.Start();
    tid2.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

public static void Thread1()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
    Console.Write(string.Format("Thread1 {0}", i)); 
    }
}

public static void Thread2()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
    Console.Write(string.Format("Thread2 {0}", i)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: They do run in parallel, [see here](http://ideone.com/OSjF0b). Perhaps they are too short and accidentally finish too fast to have the chance to interleave. Have you tried changing the number of iterations (like `1000` instead of `10`)?

Comment: You're at the mercy of the thread scheduler.  If one thread happens to finish before the scheduler decides it's time to run the other thread, this is what you'll see.

Comment: Printing 10 times in console could happen very fast. So your thread1 could already have finished the work before thread2 has started. You need to give some more work for the threads to make the probability of interleaving high.

Comment: To see them actually running in parallel, you can use `Thread.Sleep()` to halt the execution inside the loops. For 500ms, for example. But don't use `Thread.Sleep()` otherwise in code, unless you really know what you're doing. Usually it's not the correct choice.

Comment: put in a `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the loop iterations, then you might see parallelism

Comment: They are actually running in parallel. However, you can read this article to enhance your code and be sure that it is happening. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460705(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have reverted your question to the previous version. If you have found a solution, it does not belong in your question. It belongs as an answer. If you have additional questions, then you should ask a new question (after making sure it's not a duplicate and doing basic research first).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this way i achieve my goal. here is the code

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff("Task1"));
            Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff("Task2"));
            Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff("Task3"));
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

            Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void doStuff(string strName)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strName + " " + i.ToString());
                Thread.Yield();
            }
        }
    }
```

i got a another nice example of Task library from this url **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460705%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.**

### here is the code

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Retrieve Darwin's "Origin of the Species" from Gutenberg.org.
            string[] words = CreateWordArray(@"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2009/2009.txt");

            #region ParallelTasks
            // Perform three tasks in parallel on the source array
            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");
                GetLongestWord(words);
            },  // close first Action

                             () =>
                             {
                                 Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                                 GetMostCommonWords(words);
                             }, //close second Action

                             () =>
                             {
                                 Console.WriteLine("Begin third task...");
                                 GetCountForWord(words, "species");
                             } //close third Action
                         ); //close parallel.invoke

            Console.WriteLine("Returned from Parallel.Invoke");
            #endregion

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        #region HelperMethods
        private static void GetCountForWord(string[] words, string term)
        {
            var findWord = from word in words
                           where word.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())
                           select word;

            Console.WriteLine(@"Task 3 -- The word ""{0}"" occurs {1} times.",
                term, findWord.Count());
        }

        private static void GetMostCommonWords(string[] words)
        {
            var frequencyOrder = from word in words
                                 where word.Length > 6
                                 group word by word into g
                                 orderby g.Count() descending
                                 select g.Key;

            var commonWords = frequencyOrder.Take(10);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Task 2 -- The most common words are:");
            foreach (var v in commonWords)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("  " + v);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        private static string GetLongestWord(string[] words)
        {
            var longestWord = (from w in words
                               orderby w.Length descending
                               select w).First();

            Console.WriteLine("Task 1 -- The longest word is {0}", longestWord);
            return longestWord;
        }


        // An http request performed synchronously for simplicity. 
        static string[] CreateWordArray(string uri)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving from {0}", uri);

            // Download a web page the easy way. 
            string s = new WebClient().DownloadString(uri);

            // Separate string into an array of words, removing some common punctuation. 
            return s.Split(
                new char[] { ' ', '\u000A', ',', '.', ';', ':', '-', '_', '/' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

They are running in parallel. Here is adjusted code to see it better:

```
    private void test()
    {
        Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
        Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));

        tid1.Start();
        tid2.Start();
        Console.Write(string.Format("Done"));

    }
    static void Thread1()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Thread1 {0}", i));
            Thread.Yield();
        }
    }

    static void Thread2()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Thread2 {0}", i));
            Thread.Yield();
        }
    }
```

And here is output:
DoneThread1 1Thread2 1Thread1 2Thread2 2Thread1 3Thread2 3Thread1 4Thread2 4Thread1 5Thread2 5Thread1 6Thread2 6Thread1 7Thread2 7Thread1 8Thread2 8Thread1 9Thread2 9Thread1 10Thread2 10

Comment: It tells the operating system that the thread is done with it's timeslice - the operating system can then decide to give an execution time slice to another thread. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: please see my updated code done with TPL. Thread.Yield() works but when we executing a routine by multiple task then how could i print task name ?.

Comment: In simple words Yield() means "System, please decide which thread to run". Then System decides. It could be any other thread which is ready to execute or it could be current thread as well - whatever System decides. You can call Yield() as many times as you want - it doesn't mean to stop execution. It means to give availability to another thread to run. If your current thread has bigger priority it will continue to run. If you have many CPU and System uses them then every CPU will run one thread. And you can print whatever you want including task name or, better, Thread name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Parallel.Invoke() method. **But it will only work with .Net 4 and above.**

```
  public ParallelDemo()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => {
                PrintCount(-10000, 0);
            },
            () => {
                PrintCount(1, 10000);
            }
        );
    }
    public void PrintCount(int LowLimit , int UpperLimit)
    {
        for (int i = LowLimit; i <=UpperLimit; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> {0}" , i);
        }
    }
```

Output (Not same for all the systems): [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MSyP.png)

Answer (score 2):

They run parallel, but start with a time delay that is bigger than the runtime of each thread itself. Toss in a delay after each `Console.WriteLine` and you'll see.

By the way, the more elegant way of starting a new thread is

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    //code here
});
```