# Start multiple process and redirect output async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, process

i'm challanging myself with something that is difficult for me..

I would like to have a "Master terminal" that runs "slave terminals".
The slave are started with the "Redirect output" option (RedirectStandardOutput).
The slave must run async and the Master should manage the "ReadLine" from the slave.
While the slave are running, the Master must be able to execute other actions.

My actual code:

```
static void StartTerminal(string ExecPath, int DefaultPort, string Arguments = "")
    {
        int port = DefaultPort;
        if (usedPorts.Contains(port)) port = nextPort;
        while(usedPorts.Contains(nextPort))
        {
            nextPort++;
            port = nextPort;
        }
        usedPorts.Add(port);
        string _arguments = "/port:" + port;
        _arguments += Arguments;

        //* Create your Process
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet ";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = ExecPath + " /c " + _arguments;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        //* Set your output and error (asynchronous) handlers
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutErrorHandler);
        //* Start process and handlers

        ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(() => {
            bool ret = process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        });
        Thread th = new Thread(ths);
        th.Start();

        //process.Start();
        //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        //process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        //process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

As you can see, i tried both with and without starting a new Thread.
With the thread seems fine, i reach the end of the Main void before the slave terminal has completed the operations but i'm then blocked on the request of "ReadLine" of the slave. The user must press Enter to continue and i don't want this..

Can you help me please?
Do you suggest a different approach?

Thanks, regards.

**Edit 1:**
I want to manage the condition where the Slave Terminal is waiting for an "Enter" because it could be developed by 3rd parties that could ignore my guidelines where i say to do not use `Console.ReadLine()` (ok, is not my problem but i like stupid proof software).
The Master Terminal is managing an undefined number of Slave Terminals and logging all the output of the Slaves plus running a Watchdog that restarts a Slave if it crash.
The Master is also receiving commands to start/stop/reboot a Slave and/or other commands.

Comment: I think I finally get it, so `StartTerminal` essentially runs child processes, that *could* contain a `ReadLine` (or another command, that can block the program flow). I think what you need is asynchronous treads or tasks, where each one should call your `StartTerminal( ... )` method. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: You don't need a *thread* to start a process. Separate processes run on different threads *by definition*. Just call `process.Start()`

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? There's nothing related to multithreading in this code, just two processes communicating through their input/output streams. If you wanted to process data in parallel or asynchronously there are many ways that are 100000 times faster, better, more scalable than using two threads. For example, `Parallel.ForEach()` will process data using all cores in parallel. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: If you want two or more workers in a pipeline to process data, check the Dataflow classes, eg ActionBlock, TransformBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Process.BeginOutputReadLine();` and `Process.BeginErrorReadLine();` execute `asynchronously`, according to [Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, which means they do not block the program execution (or in other words: the program does not wait for those methods to finish executing).

You probably want to set some booleans to indicate when data has finished reading in `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` event handlers and in main method add a loop that would not allow the program to finish until both methods are executed.

```
private void DataReceivedEventHandler( [parameters] ){
    //I believe this is the part where you read the actual stream
    outputDataReceived = true;
}//do the same for ErrorDataReceived
while (!outputDataReceived && !errorDataReceived){
   wait(1000); //The actual method might be different, maybe sleep( 1000 ) or thread.sleep ( you can also set a different interval )
}
```

**Edit (Irrelevant edits removed)**:
[Asynchronous tasks,treads and Parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626685/how-to-run-two-threads-parallel) are described in answers of this question. I believe any one of the answers will suit your needs.

Basically, use any of the code samples in the answers of the linked question, just call your `StartTerminal( )` method in the thread / task / parallel invocation. Use the code in the answers to create asynchronous processing and implement logic to prevent program from reaching its end until all threads have finished doing their work. Pseudo code:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

private void StartTerminal(int id, params){
     //all of your code keep it asynchornous

    while( !outputDataReceived && !errorDataReceived ){
        sleep( 1000 ); //delay between checks
    } //Makes sure this thread does not close until data is received, implement any other logic that should keep the thread alive here
}

public static void main(...){

    foreach(ParameterSet params in Parameters){ //Create thread list with different parameters
       var thread =  new Thread( StartTerminal(params) );
       threads.Add( thread );
    }

    while( !threads.isEmpty() ) ){ //if it is empty, all threads finished the job and got deleted, loop is skipped and program closes
        var threadsToRemove = new List<Thread>();
        foreach(Thread t in threads){ //start unstarted threads
          if(t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted){
            threads[i].Start( ).
          }elseif(t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped){ //remove stopped threads
            threadsToRemove.Add(t).
          }//Implement other logic for suspended, aborted and other threads...
        }
        foreach(Thread t in threadsToRemove){
           threads.Remove(t);
        }

        sleep(1000); //delay between checks
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Give these patterns to your slave terminal developers (if they don't know how to do it themselves, without blocking everything), because once 'ReadLine' is called synchronously, there is nothing (reasonable) you can do until the user presses enter.

When possible (especially when programming hardware, such as controllers) use  triggers instead of 'ReadLines' for user inputs

```
HardwareButtonEnter.Press += delegate{ userInput = eventParameters.userInput; 
    UserInputReceived = true;}; //This is really hardware API specific code, only the boolean is important

//start an async thread/process for reading master terminal input.
while(1 = 1){
   if(UserInputReceived){
      ProcessUserInput().
   }elseif(masterTerminalDataReceived){
      ProcessMasterTerminalData().
   }
}
```

If you cannot use triggers (for example when programming a console application) put blocking statements in asynchronous threads and process them when threads finish.

```
//Start your (async) ReadLine thread. Make sure it also sets UserInputReceived = true when it ends
//Start your async process read thread. also get it to set some boolean.
while( 1 = 1){
   if(threads.Any( t => t.Status = Finished ){
      if(UserInputReceived){
      }elseif(terminalInputReceived){
       ..
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The code that is after `StartTerminal([params]);` is not executing until the user press Enter when the slave terminal requests it. I need to avoid this managing an "automatic Enter" when required.

Comment: Could you update your question explaining what you want to achieve (step by step), because ReadLine method ONLY executes when Enter is pressed (a line is submitted). If you do not need any input from the user, maybe remove the ReadLine entirely? If you DO need input from the user, i do not understand why you need to wait for the user. Do you only wait for the "Enter" because slave terminal does not "know" when server finishes the job?

Comment: Question edited. I want to ignore a ReadLine() that should not be present in the Slave Terminal.

Comment: Fianlaly tested the code! I had to change it a bit but is ok ;)
What i still don't know is how to manage the `Console.ReadLine()` of the slave Terminal. It still blocks my main Terminal.. Using `process.WaitForExit();` when starting the process, the Thread (when ReadLine calls) goes in `System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin` but then if i do `thread.Interrupt()` there is an exception. Any idea?

Comment: The key here is to start ALL of your threads/task asynchronous. If you start your threads correctly (this is the part you should look into and test with a simple use-case) individual threads will get blocked (by blocking commands), but the main process should keep on going. I don't remember exactly how it goes, but I think it was something similar to what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I saw the blocking/non-blocking difference when using `process.WaitForExit();`. I can then avoid that the main thread is blocked but i can't send a command to the terminal to "skip" the `Console.ReadLine()`.
Not a real problem, i'll try to figure out as son as i have time.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you have no control over code in slave terminal, you cannot do that. I think the easiest solution is to force the slave terminal developers to use thread-like processing. So either check for user input and master terminal input in own threads or (if hardware programing is taking place) use flags instead of linear logic (will update my answer to explain flags a little).